# Is it okay to turn off Intel VMD after updating Windows 11?

Tags: windows, boot, bios, windows-11, intel

I don't know anything about Intel VMD and have no idea what it is. I updated my Windows 11 on my ASUS laptop and after restart I get into blue screen and I did everything but none of it worked. I disabled VMD in boot settings and Windows finally came up. I want to know if I should turn it back on or not? I heard if I turn it back on it goes to blue screen again and the only way is to reinstall Windows. If I keep the VMD off what will happen?

Answer (score 5):

[Intel Volume Management Device (VMD)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-volume-management-device-overview.htm)
is specifically designed for enterprise-grade management of NVMe SSDs
connected to Intel Xeon CPUs.
It is mostly aimed at making RAID I/O more efficient.

When you disable VMD, your disks use plain NVMe, which is perhaps
what you need.

To summarize, this technology is most likely useless for your purpose,
so can stay disabled, especially if your computer doesn't work
work well when it's enabled.